# iPhone 7 is frozen and I can't turn it off

Tags: iphone, keyboard, display, performance

I went onto my iPhone 7 and tried to get into an app but couldn't I then tried swiping sideways along the screen but it wouldn't move. I tried turning it off but it got stuck on the sliding part and wouldn't turn off completely. I can't receive any calls and I'm now stuck on my lock screen and can't get into my phone because the code doesn't go in when I type it.

Comment: Try holding down the power button and the home button simultaneously. That should force power down & restart.

Comment: thanks, I've tried that, it goes to the sliding part where it's about to turn off then freezes again

Answer (score 1):

I would repeat this process two times 5 minutes apart and one last time 15 minutes later and them move on to the more painful remedies.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201559
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201412 (try the force reset only unless you want to escalate to restores)

Once you’ve exhaused asking nicely and not so nicely for the device to redstart, you have options that require a computer or more time:

1. Wait for the battery to die / exhaust itself. Then plug it in and see if it works or needs to be restored.
2. Call the phone / text the phone / try to get something to work that you can accept from the lock screen to know it’s still basically functioning. Sometimes after answering the call, you can then get to the unlocked device - other times, you’re back at the lock screen.
3. Connect to iTunes and restore the device.

Comment: thank you. I've tried most of that and it doesn't work. I'll try letting it run out of charge